# NOW() function returns wrong timestamp on my web host

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am working on a project right now and I am using the NOW() function to get the exact time when users make a reservation, it works fine on my local machine but after I uploaded it on my web host and when I tested it, it showed a different time! I thought maybe it is getting the time from the server but how can I change that server time (If I am right) and make it more similar to my clock?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: How different are the times from each other? Are you in the same time zone as the server? How are you handling timezone offsets? Are both your server and home machine using NTP to keep the clock in sync?

Comment: this is on my web server: 2011-09-19 17:53:34
this is on my local machine: 2011-09-20 01:08:22

I dont think I am in the saem time zone as the server! No they are not using NTP.

How can I handle timezone offsets?

Comment: A web host that doesn't use ntp to sync clocks?  go find another one, if they can't get something that basic straight one can fear for the rest of their infrastructure.

Comment: it is pretty cheap host! I am using it only for testing so.. that is why it doesnt use ntp

Comment: @toocool given that reliable ntp servers can be used for free eg via `www.pool.ntp.org` and setup on all major OS'es is a nobrainer that shouldn't take more than few minutes to setup they must be really serious about that 'cheap' label :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `date_default_timezone_set()` to set your PHP timezone. And `mysql_query("SET time_zone = '...'")` to set the MySQL timezone.

But I can't help you with the wildly inaccurate clock, you will need to ask them to fix it.

Comment: Problem solved, I solved it by adding 7 more hours to it like this: **DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)**

Comment: Ouch! That is a terrible way to solve that. If you ever move to a new host, or if they fix their clock you will regret doing that.

Comment: I really like your comment, I guess you are right.. but I dont think they are going to change their clock! but If I change my host I am going to check this again, or maybe I am going to find another better solution for this (if it gets serious) anyway thanks for your comment for some reason I liked it